# NGINX "password" protect directories

Tags: nginx, password-protected

I have an nginx server. I'd like to have directories available online but only if a certain password is supplied.
Would it be bad to do something like:

```
location /password=mysuperstrongpassword {
      root /mydir
}
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Along the same lines, can someone point me in the direction of how to write a script that creates a new password every week or so, rewrites this page, and emails me the new password?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your super-strong password is likely to be stored in plain-text logs, your analytics solution, etc.

nginx has a module to do the standard Apache-style [HTTP basic authentication](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html).